# @TypeChecked - Ambiguous method

Tags: groovy, compiler-errors, typechecking

I have a following code:

```
@TypeChecked
class SomeClass {

  def someMethod( BridgeEvent event ){
    event.complete true // here comes the compile error
  }

}
```

the line shows an error in eclipse:

> Groovy:[Static type checking] - Reference to method is ambiguous. Cannot choose between [void io.vertx.groovy.ext.web.handler.sockjs.BridgeEvent#complete(java.lang.Boolean), void io.vertx.groovy.ext.web.handler.sockjs.BridgeEvent#complete(java.lang.Object)]

The 1st method comes from the `BridgeEvent` class, the 2nd from it's superclass.

If I remove `@TypeChecked` the code is working just fine.

How can I fix the problem?

UPDATE:

I tried @tim-yates' solution `event.complete Boolean.TRUE` and compile error disappears, but the `complete(java.lang.Object)` method is doing something different, than the `complete(boolean)`. So I need to call the later method.

For now I rewritten the code so:

```
@TypeChecked
class SomeClass {

  def someMethod( BridgeEvent event ){
    complete event
  }

  @TypeChecked( SKIP )
  private void complete( BridgeEvent event ){
    event.complete true
  }

}
```

and it's working great again, but the way it looks...

Comment: Tried: `event.complete Boolean.TRUE`?

Comment: the compile error dissapears, but the `complete(java.lang.Object)` is doing something different, than the `complete(boolean)`

Comment: Can you trace it and see which one gets called?  Groovy seems to think it's `complete(java.lang.Boolean)` (as in the error message)

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that the `complete(Object)` method gets called for `Boolean.TRUE`, as the app behaves strange :)